# Implementing Xamarin Forms context actions

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement context actions on my list in Xamarin Forms but can't get it to work.
I am not using XAML, but instead creating my layout in code.
I am trying to follow the steps in https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Context_Actions and I want to push a new page when "Edit" is clicked.

I cleaned up my code and removed my feeble attempts to make things work.

So this is my custom list cell:

```
public class PickerListCell : TextCell
{
    public PickerListCell ()
    {
        var moreAction = new MenuItem { Text = App.Translate ("Edit") };
        moreAction.SetBinding (MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding ("."));
        moreAction.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
            var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
            var option = (PickerListPage.OptionListItem)mi.CommandParameter;

            var recId = new Guid (option.Value);

            // This is where I want to call a method declared in my page to be able to push a page to the Navigation stack

        };
        ContextActions.Add (moreAction);
    }
}
```

And here is my model:

```
public class OptionListItem
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the page:

```
public class PickerPage : ContentPage
{
    ListView listView { get; set; }

    public PickerPage (OptionListItem [] items)
    {
        listView = new ListView () ;

        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = { listView }
        };

        var cell = new DataTemplate (typeof (PickerListCell));
        cell.SetBinding (PickerListCell.TextProperty, "Caption");
        cell.SetBinding (PickerListCell.CommandParameterProperty, "Value");


        listView.ItemTemplate = cell;
        listView.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    // This is the method I want to activate when the context action is called
    void OnEditAction (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cell = (sender as Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem).BindingContext as PickerListCell;

        await Navigation.PushAsync (new RecordEditPage (recId), true);
    }

}
```

As you can see by my comments in the code, I have indicated where I believe things are missing.

Please assist guys!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so with the help of some posts, specifically this one https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27881/best-practive-mvvm-navigation-when-command-is-not-available, I came to the following solution, though I'm not perfectly satisfied with the way it looks.

My custom cell now announces when a command is being executed using MessagingCenter:

```
public class PickerListCell : TextCell
{

    public PickerListCell ()
    {
        var moreAction = new MenuItem { Text = App.Translate ("Edit") };
        moreAction.SetBinding (MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding ("."));
        moreAction.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
            var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
            var option = (PickerListPage.OptionListItem)mi.CommandParameter;

            var recId = new Guid (option.Value);

            // HERE I send a request to open a new page. This looks a 
            // bit crappy with a magic string. It will be replaced with a constant or enum
            MessagingCenter.Send<OptionListItem, Guid> (this, "PushPage", recId);
        };
        ContextActions.Add (moreAction);
    }
}
```

And in my PickerPage constructor I added this subscription to the Messaging service:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<OptionListItem, Guid> (this, "PushPage", (sender, recId) => {
            Navigation.PushAsync (new RecordEditPage (recId), true);
        });
```

All this works just find, but I'm not sure if this is the way it was intended to. I feel like the binding should be able to solve this without the Messaging Service, but I can't find out how to bind to a method on the page, only to a model, and I don't want to pollute my model with methods that have dependencies on XF.

Answer (score 4):

Probably is too late for you, but can help others. The way i've found to do this is passing the instance of page on creation the ViewCell.

```
public class PickerListCell : TextCell
{
    public PickerListCell (PickerPage myPage)
    {
        var moreAction = new MenuItem { Text = App.Translate ("Edit") };
        moreAction.SetBinding (MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding ("."));
        moreAction.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
            var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
            var option = (PickerListPage.OptionListItem)mi.CommandParameter;

            var recId = new Guid (option.Value);

            myPage.OnEditAction();

        };
      ContextActions.Add (moreAction);
    }
}
```

So, in your page:

```
public class PickerPage : ContentPage
{
    ListView listView { get; set; }

    public PickerPage (OptionListItem [] items)
    {
        listView = new ListView () ;

        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = { listView }
        };

        var cell  = new DataTemplate(() => {return new PickerListCell(this); });            
        cell.SetBinding (PickerListCell.TextProperty, "Caption");
        cell.SetBinding (PickerListCell.CommandParameterProperty, "Value");


        listView.ItemTemplate = cell;
        listView.ItemsSource = items;
    }


   void OnEditAction (object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        var cell = (sender as Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem).BindingContext as PickerListCell;

        await Navigation.PushAsync (new RecordEditPage (recId), true);
   }

}
```